# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/36}x\tan (12x)\text{dx}$, trouble with algebra?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/36}x\tan (12x)\text{dx}$$

I have $u=x$, $du=dx$, $dv=\tan^2{12x}dx$ and $v=\dfrac{1}{12}\tan(12x)-x$.

Using integration by parts $uv-\int vdu$, I get:

$$x(\dfrac{1}{12}\tan(12x)-x)|_{0}^{\pi/36}-\int_{0}^{\pi/36}(\dfrac{1}{12}\tan(12x)-x)dx$$
$$x(\dfrac{1}{12}\tan(12x)-x)|_{0}^{\pi/36}-\frac{1}{12}\int_{0}^{\pi/36}\tan(12x)dx-\int_{0}^{\pi/36}xdx$$
$$x(\dfrac{1}{12}\tan(12x)-x)|_{0}^{\pi/36}-\frac{1}{12}(\ln|\sec(12x)|)|_{0}^{\pi/36}-\frac{x^2}{2}|_{0}^{\pi/36}$$

Evaluating each term for the limits of integration I get:

$$\frac{\pi}{36}(\frac{1}{12}\tan(\frac{\pi}{3})-\frac{\pi}{36})-\frac{1}{12}(\frac{1}{12}\ln2)-\frac{(\pi/36)^2}{2}$$

Simplifying this I get:
$$\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{432}-\frac{\pi^2}{1296}-\frac{\ln2}{144}-\frac{\pi^2}{2592}$$

This is very close to the correct answer, for some reason I have an extra term $\dfrac{\pi^2}{1296}$.

I have went over my work a couple of times and cannot find my mistake. Where in the problem would this extra term cancel out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x(\dfrac{1}{12}\tan(12x)-x)|_{0}^{\pi/36}-\int_{0}^{\pi/36}(\dfrac{1}{12}\tan(12x)-x)dx$$
$$x(\dfrac{1}{12}\tan(12x)-x)|_{0}^{\pi/36}-\frac{1}{12}\int_{0}^{\pi/36}\tan(12x)dx\color{red}{\underbrace{-}_{\text{sign error}}}\int_{0}^{\pi/36}xdx$$

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that the first integral had a negative sign in front of it...